# iOS Corebluetooth services never discovered, but are visible in advertisingData of delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using iOS 6 Corebluetooth with Alert Notification service.

The services don't show up in peripheral for some reason, althought the advertisingData in delegate method looks correct.

Here is the delegate method:

```
 (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    bool ourGuy = NO;
    NSLog(@"DATA: %@", advertisementData);

    NSArray *keys = [advertisementData allKeys];
    for (int i = 0; i < [keys count]; ++i) {
        id key = [keys objectAtIndex: i];
        NSString *keyName = (NSString *) key;
        NSObject *value = [advertisementData objectForKey: key];
        if ([value isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]]) {

            printf("   key: %s\n", [keyName cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

            if ([keyName isEqualToString: @"kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"] ){

                NSArray *values = (NSArray *) value;
                for (int j = 0; j < [values count]; ++j) {
                    if ([[values objectAtIndex: j] isKindOfClass: [CBUUID class]]) {
                        CBUUID *uuid = [values objectAtIndex: j];                        

                        NSString *uuidString = [uuid representativeString];

                        NSLog(@"FOUND SERVICE UUID %@", uuidString);

                        if ([uuidString isEqualToString:kalertNotificationServiceUUIDString]){

                            NSLog(@"Connecting");

                            if (![foundPeripherals containsObject:peripheral]) {

                                ourGuy = YES;                                   
                            }                               
                        }

                    } else {
                        const char *valueString = [[value description] cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                        printf("      value(%d): %s\n", j, valueString);
                    }
                }

            }
        } else {
            const char *valueString = [[value description] cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            printf("   key: %s, value: %s\n", [keyName cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding], valueString);
        }
    }

    if (ourGuy){
        [foundPeripherals addObject:peripheral];
                peripheral.delegate = self;
        [centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    }


}
```

Here is what the log looks like:

```
2013-08-25 23:30:17.417 myControl[688:907] DATA: {
    kCBAdvDataLocalName = myTEST;
    kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
        "Unknown (<1811>)",
        "Unknown (<180f>)"
    );
}
   key: kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs


2013-08-25 23:30:17.419 myControl[688:907] FOUND SERVICE UUID 1811
2013-08-25 23:30:17.421 myControl[688:907] Connecting
2013-08-25 23:30:17.422 myControl[688:907] FOUND SERVICE UUID 180f
   key: kCBAdvDataLocalName, value: myTEST
   key: kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel, value: -8
```

The delegate method for the service discovery:

```
- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error{

    for (int i=0; i < peripheral.services.count; i++) {
        CBService *s = [peripheral.services objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@" UUUID %@", [s.UUID representativeString]);
        //        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:s];
    }
}
```

The log from that method:

```
2013-08-25 23:30:18.266 myControl[688:907]  UUUID 1800
2013-08-25 23:30:18.269 myControl[688:907]  UUUID 1801
```

These are two UUIDs for the BLE GATT and GAP. Services for the peripheral that are seen in advertisementData never show up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your code: do you implement the `peripheral:didDiscoverServices:` callback, and how do you handle it? In the simplest case it should be something like this:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
  /* Find all characteristics for all discovered services */
  for (CBService *service in peripheral.services)
  {
    [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
  }
}
```

In addition, what's in the advertisement data and what is provided are two different stories. The peripheral can advertise any services even those that are not provided I can easily start advertisement in iOS like this:

```
NSDictionary *data = @{CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:
        @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180D"], [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"FFBC"]]};
[peripheralManager startAdvertising:data];
```

Without adding any of these services.

I suggest you try to discover the peripheral first with a working app, like the BLEUtility or BLExplr and see if the peripheral is really providing those services.

Comment: Thank you, actually I am implementing the peripheral:didDiscoverServices: I copy-pasted wrong code. I will edit the question. I will try the BLEUtility and BLExplr and will get back. The peripheral is non-iOS device by the way (if that matters).

Comment: Let me know of the results of the tests and please add the code where you invoke the `discoverServices:` method on the peripheral.

Comment: Added the code to the question (instead of didDiscoverCharaceristisc:) and checked the BLEUtility. The device indeed advertises one services, but provides only the most basic ones. I guess solving that would demand diving into the device C code?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, this means you are on the dark side of the issue. Seemingly the iOS code is doing what it should. But at least now you have some toools to test before trying to debug your code.

Comment: @allprog do you know how to add more information in the AdvertisementData NSDictionary?

Comment: You can't add arbitrary keys. All you can use is defined by the CBAdvertisementData* enum literals. And some of them may be restricted and not available to you. The documentation is very sparse but you can search the net for the different keys to understand what they do.